# Error de conexión Mysqli en 000Webhost

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php5

Estoy intentando conectarme a la base de datos que tengo en 000webhost desde el mismo cpanel, ya cambie la versión a Php 5.7 que es en la que estoy desarrollando, también probé cambiándola a Php 5.4 pero sigue igual y sale el siguiente error.

Este es el código que estoy usando.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass"); //connection
    mysqli_select_db($con,"bd"); 
?>
```

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'2a02:4780:bad:f00d::10' (using password: YES) in /storage/ssd5/085/3193085/public_html/conexionsqlifa.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /storage/ssd5/085/3193085/public_html/conexionsqlifa.php on line 3

les dejo el enlace para que vean, ademas una conexión con Mysql que si funciona.

Conexión Mysqli que no funciona.
http://inmobiliariasai.000webhostapp.com/conexionsqlifa.php

Conexión Mysql que si funciona.
http://inmobiliariasai.000webhostapp.com/conexion2.php

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada el usuario jamás podría ser `'root'` ya que ese servicio siempre brinda un usuario con esta sintaxis `"id1111111_nombrebd"`, un nombre de base de datos con `"id1111111_nombreuser"` y el host siempre será `localhost`.

Esto se puede verificar en la  sección "*Administrar bases de datos*".

Podría quedar algo tal que así:
**cone.php:**

```
<?php $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id1111111_nombreuser", "contraseña", "id1111111_nombrebd"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas:
¿Has probado a usar mysql_connect con 4 parámetros?. Yo la uso así:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(server,user,pass,nombreDB);
```

Además en php.net el ejemplo lo indica así:

```
$enlace = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");
```

Sin más datos no puedo explicarte más. A efectos generales revisa que el usuario que estás intentando usar este creado y tenga privilegios sobre esa BD.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que sea un tema de la configuración de mysql y cómo están configurados los usuarios. Para permitir que un usuario se conecte desde cualquier lado, el usuario debe existir como `'user'@'%'` en la configuración de la base de datos. Esta configuración de usuario la podés ver desde PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como lo dice Niche, se debe a que la autenticación del usuario en la base de datos está fallando y por la inexistencia de la conexión, la selección de la base de datos tampoco se puede hacer. Revisa muy bien que los valores introducidos dentro de la funcion mysqli_connect(); sean válidos.

Comment: Esto se acerca más a un comentario, recuerda que no debes usar la sección de respuestas para realizar opiniones, sugerencias o comentarios propiamente tal :)

Comment: Lo haría si pudiera, pero no tengo 50 de reputacion.