# mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli bool given in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Al momento de conectar mi base de datos me sale el siguiente error **mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli bool given in**

Adjunto captura del error del que se me da.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo de la conexion a la base de datos es la siguiente

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
$db = 'sist';
$conection = @mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
mysqli_set_charset($conection,'utf8');

if(!$conection){
   echo"error de conexion";
}
```

Comment: Básicamente lo que te está diciendo es que la conexión no se ha realizado correctamente. Para ver el error de conexion quita la @ del @mysqli_connect y verás el error de conexión a arreglar.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario, el error es el siguiente  **Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user ' id19625040_root'@'2a02:4780:bad:f00d::16' (using password: YES) in /storage/ssd1/040/19625040/public_html/conexion.php on line 10**
Lo que no me queda claro es porque sigue saliendo este error ya que el usuario contraseña y el nombre de la base de datos es correcta.

Comment: El mensaje es claro: El acceso ha sido denegado al usuario `id19625040_root` en la base de datos llamada `2a02:4780:bad:f00d::16`. ¿Ese es el nombre de tu usuario y de la base de datos? ¿La contraseña es correcta? Debes verificar eso, y si todo está OK, entonces prueba a limpiar la caché, pues puede que se haya quedado en memoria un código antiguo con error. Por cierto, evita silenciar los errores en el código usando `@`, es una mala práctica, es renunciar a una de tus tareas principales como programador: manejar adecuadamente los errores.

Comment: Mirando [estas respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233491/263200) de una pregunta similar me pregunto si esto: `$db = 'sist';` no deberia ser esto: `$db = 'id19625040_sist';`

Comment: deja de usar `@` para suprimir errores es una muy mala practica. ademas usa `or die(mysql_error());` al final del `mysqli_connect`